# How to find the Covariance of Bivariate Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability, integration, covariance

We have the joint PDF for $X$ and $Y$ as:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2b^2-c^2}}   \exp\left\{\frac{-(a^2(x-m)^2 - 2c(x-m)(y-n)+b^2(y-n)^2)}{2(a^2b^2 - c^2)}\right\} dx dy$$

Where $m,n \in\mathbb{R}, a>0, b>0, c\in\mathbb{R}, |c|<ab$.

Now I am trying to find Cov($X,Y$), **only through integration of transcendental functions or through properties of Variance, essentially at an undergrad level of Calculus**.

The way I've been attempting to do it is by replacing variables, completing the square, and getting:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt d a ^2b^2} \cdot \iint_{\mathbb{R^2}}\exp\left\{\frac{-(\frac{t^2}{2ab}+\frac{w^2}{2d})}{b}\right\}\cdot {\left\{tw+\frac{ct^2}{ab}\right\}} dt dw$$

by making the following substitutions:

$d=a^2b^2-c^2, (x-m) = u, (y-n) = v, au = z, bv = t$, and finally, $w = z - \frac{ct}{ab}$.

Now applying all of these transformations, I get the double integral above. But now I am confused as to what to do. Also, I may be overthinking this question, and making there is an easier way through polar coordinates that I can reach the same result? If you had any feedback it would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some algebra mistakes in your calculation, leading to a wrong answer. A cleaner set of substitutions is:
$$
z:=\frac{x-m}b,\quad t:=\frac{y-n}a,\quad\rho:=\frac c{ab}.\tag1
$$
Assuming you have established that $E(X)=m$ and $E(Y)=n$, the covariance between $X$ and $Y$ is
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\iint (x-m)(y-n)f(x,y)\,dxdy\tag2.
$$
Applying the substitutions (1) you will get
$$
\begin{align}
&\iint bz\, at\, f(bz+m,at+n)\,bdz\, a dt\\
& = (ab)^2\iint zt \frac1{2\pi ab\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{a^2b^2z^2-2cabzt+b^2a^2t^2}{2(a^2b^2-c^2)}\right\}\,dzdt\\
& = ab\iint zt \frac1{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{z^2-2\rho zt+t^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right\}\,dzdt\\
& = ab\iint zt\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi(1-\rho^2)}}\exp\left\{-\frac{(z-\rho t)^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right\}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{t^2}2\right\}\,dzdt.\tag3
\end{align}
$$
To evaluate (3), use your substitution $w:=z-\rho t$ to obtain
$$
ab\iint (w+\rho t)t\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi(1-\rho^2)}}\exp\left\{-\frac{w^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right\}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{t^2}2\right\}\,dwdt.\tag4
$$
Breaking (4) into two pieces, the first term is
$$
ab\left(\int w\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi(1-\rho^2)}}\exp\left\{-\frac{w^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right\}\,dw\right)\left( \int t\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{t^2}2\right\}\,dt\right)\tag5
$$
which equals $ab\cdot 0\cdot0$, and the second term is
$$
\rho ab\left(\int \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi(1-\rho^2)}}\exp\left\{-\frac{w^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right\}\,dw\right)\left( \int t^2\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{t^2}2\right\}\,dt\right)\tag6
$$
which equals $\rho ab\cdot1\cdot1=c$.

Comment: The question states that Cov(X,Y) = c though?

Comment: @FelicioGrande Ah, I left out a factor of $ab$ in the transformed density. Fixed.

Comment: I am very confused about how you got to number 3. I can complete the square and everything, but i have too many a and b's lying around, and don't know how to factor them out of the exponent

Comment: @FelicioGrande I have added more detail before step (3)